# How could I know where the search engine found my page?

Tags: search

I have a URL pattern that was found by the search engine, I've tried the `link` directive to find backward links. But to no avail.

So how could I know where / how the search engine found those page?

By search engine I specifically refer to Bing and Google

Comment: Welcome to the world of crawlers. A crawler indexes your main page, then follows links leading off that page.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would actually be to sign up for a Google Analytics accounts and place tracking cookies on your websites.  That way you can see where referring traffic is coming from.  The `link` directive is good but an actual tracking device such as Analytics will show you those that might not necessarily show up in the `link` searches.

Answer (score -1):

To see which of your pages have been indexed you should use the site operator:

> site:www.domain.com

This will return all of the pages Google has crawled and indexed within your site. You can also modify the search to look for certain keywords or urls

The [Google reference](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/136861?hl=en) may be useful

Answer (score -1):

The only time that I have found that Google tells you where it found links to your site, is when the page on your site is 404 Not Found.  In that case, Google has a 404 report in Webmaster Tools that includes information about what links to that URL.

If you have a valid page on your site, I've never seen Google tell you this information.   The referrer field that Googlebot sends when it crawls is always blank.  Google specifically makes the `link:` directive incomplete and useless.

Bing on the other hand has a [inbound links tool](https://ssl.bing.com/webmaster/reports/inbound/links) available in their webmaster tools.  When you log in and validate your site, they will tell you about links they find to your pages.